# Comments encouraging voting for improper reasons

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, comment-flags

Recently, a hot network question lead me to this SciFi question [Why are there so many 47s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s).  Some of the highly upvoted comments on both the question and the answer encourage other users to try to vote the posts to a "perfect" score of 47.  Examples:

- > [This question has to get 47 upvotes and stop there!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s#comment223001_97166)
- > [Congrats on a score of 47. I would upvote, but...](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s#comment223199_97168)
- > [Downvoted you to 48! Come on people, stick to the script!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s#comment223212_97168)

Are comments that encourage this kind of improper meta-voting and not actually for the standard reasons of usefulness and clarity not constructive and should they be flagged as such?  (Currently, both the question and answer have a score much higher than 47).

---

*Disclaimer* I am not a member of the SciFi community and do not know the voting culture there specifically.  I also cannot flag the comments without becoming a member.

Comment: Don't you think this is something specific to the Sci-Fi community and should be brought up on their meta? In other words, why do you believe this is an issue that should be discussed within the bigger Stack Exchange community?

Comment: @Oded I realize that voting culture is per community, but does SE have any network-wide policies on this?  This is obviously not as important as keeping spam out, but I figured that this is applicable to SE sites in general.  If it is too specific to a specific community, I can always delete this question (or you could migrate it).  I don't plan on becoming a member of Sci-Fi, so I wouldn't post it on their meta.

Comment: I think it is one post. And people are having fun with it. I don't see how this effects much of the network or even the rest of Sci-Fi. You are also assuming that because someone commented that they voted one way or another, they actually did.

Comment: @Oded I'm really more assuming that the presence of the comments incorrectly encourages others to do so.  But point taken.

Comment: Meh. I don't think this particular case is all that worrying. But don't hesitate to flag such comments if you find them noisy or problematic. Or if there are plenty, raise an "other" flag and have a mod see if they should remain or be nuked altogether.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - to assuage your fears - that post has 4 downvotes. People are just joking around.

Comment: @Oded ah thanks.  I guess I won't meddle in a community I'm not actually a part of.

Comment: @Bart if Sci-Fi folks are interested in "exploiting" hot questions to help their community growth (even though this is not an intended use of this feature) then I think noisy comments like that [should be considered harmful](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1247/516 "for the reasons explained in more details here")